# Pass data to view in express handlebar

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm struggling to get some data sent to my view page. I think it is to do with the order the code is running. This is my code;

```
exports.home = (req, res) => {
  let fileMessage = 'starting message';
  const fileSys = 'public/data/';
  const fileArray = [];
  fs.readdirSync(fileSys, (err, files) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else {
      files.forEach((file) => {
        if (path.extname(file) === '.csv') {
          fileArray.push(file);
        }
      });
      if (fileArray.length === 1) {
        fileMessage = 'OK';
        console.log(fileMessage);
      }
      if (fileArray.length > 1) {
        fileMessage = 'loads';
        console.log(fileMessage);
      }
      if (fileArray.length === 0) {
        fileMessage = 'none';
        console.log(fileMessage);
      }
    }
  });
  console.log('before render');
  res.render('index', {
    title: 'Admin',
    fileMessage,
    home: true
  });
  console.log('after render');
};
```

In this format I get the following output;

```
before render
after render
```

Where clearly the file read is not happening.

If I change to `readdir()` i get;

```
before render
after render
none
```

So the file read function is occurring and getting the correct value however the value passed into the view template is still 'starting message'

I can't work out how to get this in the correct order so that i can pass the `fileMessage` variable to my view file with either, OK, loads, none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code ,you are using `readdirSync` in wrong way. If you want to use Callbacks ,then use `readdir` only ,Also as the operation is async you are getting the initial value of `fileMessage` rendered in the browser (the data is being sent to the browser even before the file reading is done),So you should send the response back to browser in the `callBack function` like the way I did below.

```
exports.home = (req, res) => {
        let fileMessage = 'starting message';
        const fileSys = 'public/data/';
        const fileArray = [];
        fs.readdir(fileSys, (err, files) => {
          if (err) console.log(err);
          else {
              console.log(files);
            files.forEach((file) => {
              if (path.extname(file) === '.csv') {
                fileArray.push(file);
              }
            });
            if (fileArray.length === 1) {
              fileMessage = 'OK';
              console.log(fileMessage);
            }
            if (fileArray.length > 1) {
              fileMessage = 'loads';
              console.log(fileMessage);
            }
            if (fileArray.length === 0) {
              fileMessage = 'none';
              console.log(fileMessage);
            }
          }
          console.log('before render');
      res.send(fileMessage)
        console.log('after render');
        });
        
      }
```

And if you are planning to use [readirSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options)

> (Which I typically won't suggest doing because it will block the event
> loop)

Then the correct syntax would be

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
  
// Function to get current filenames 
// in directory 
filenames = fs.readdirSync("public/data);
```

Then you can iterate the `fileNames` Array.

Comment: thanks - I moved the res.render function within the callback and it is working now